# DataGrid column width sync

Tags: wpf

I have a listbox which items are built horizontally.

Also i have a DataGrid whose Columns are built dynamically.

Each ListBoxItem is coresponding to a DataGrid Column

I want to sync between the DataGrid Column and the right ListBoxItem, so each ListBoxItem will be parallel to a column. Also when resizing the column , it will change the size of the ListBoxItem.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind item width with to the datagrid column actualwidth

```
      <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <DataGrid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Some col 1" x:Name="first"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Some col 2" x:Name="second" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Some col 3" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>

            </DataGrid>

            <ListBox>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <Button Content="button 1" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=first}"></Button>
                <Button Content="button 2" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=second}"></Button>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

If you create them dynamically, set binding in code.